# Update appsettings.json in Webpack

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, visual-studio-2015, appsettings

I would like my webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js to make changes to values in the appsettings.json file upon build.

Is there a straightforward way to do that?  I'm using ASP.NET core in Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks.